# How to make index file the home page/front page in a Wordpress website

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress account for which I have been trying to create a website. 
I have configured and launched the site. After launching, I attempted to click "url" or the "view site" option in the Wordpress dashboard. However, this action doesn't open the index file by default. It opens an empty page with the header and footer only.

After watching some videos, I tried changing the static webpage front page to index in the customize section of the dashboard. However, it still shows nothing..

How can I make the index page the default page for my Wordpress site?

Any help is appreciated..

Comment: Which version of Wordpress are you using, and are you hosting this yourself, or on a 3rd party site, such as Wordpress.com?

Answer (score 1):

`index.php` will likely be your homepage template if your homepage is set to display the latest posts.

If you're using a static page, then it will use the page template you've selected for the page. If you haven't selected a template it's going to be `page.php`.

There are some exceptions such as if you have a `front-page.php` or `home.php` template file.

For full details on how the template used to display the homepage is selected, see: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#home-page-display

Comment: @NatanDawson say for once, i haven't selected the static option , then according to you it would take the index.php as the default launch page right?, but what if mt index pages is name as just "index" instead of "index.php"..???

Comment: I would say you're probably misunderstanding what I mean by `index.php` :) `index.php` is the name of a template file inside your theme folder, it isn't the name of a page under Pages. If what you're saying is that inside your theme you have a file named just `index`, no extension, I would tell you to rename it

Comment: Thanks, `front-page.php` was the answer in my case. I'm using PolyLang for multilingual site. The usual `index.php` and `home.php` did NOT work.

Answer (score 0):

AS default in alwyas excute a index.php file if its not working so create a page as home in wordpress Admin.

Now create a file i.e. `page-home.php` 
in which include `header.php` and `footer.php` in middle of this write your cod of home page.

Or
Crate a template as `home.php` and assign this template to home page.

Then Assign home page as front page by going in

```
setting>>Reading >>Select front page >> Select her home page
```

Hope this will help you.

Thank you.